# ¿Por qué no es posible establecer null en un Objeto pasado por referencia en una función de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, paso-por-referencia

No sé por qué en el siguiente ejemplo no es posible definir null para el objeto, sin embargo, si es posible agregarle propiedades:

```js
function nullObject(obj) {
  obj.b = 2;
  obj = null; // No hace que obj sea null

  // obj.b = 2; // Si lo ejecutó aqui arroja error
}


let customObj = {
  a: 1
};

console.log("Antes de llamar al método de referencia");
console.log(customObj);

nullObject(customObj);

console.log("Despues de llamar al método de referencia");
console.log(customObj);
```

Incluso si lo configuro como null primero y luego agrego una propiedad arroja un error.

No entiendo bien este comportamiento. ¿Hay alguna razón? tal vez no estoy entendiendo cómo funciona JavaScript al pasar un argumento por referencia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript heredó esta característica de Java: Todo se pasa por valor, no por referencia. Lo que pasa es que cuando hablamos de valores "primitivos" (string, number, boolean, undefined, null y Symbol) se asume que no hay punteros, se pasa una copia del valor y además son inmutables.

Cuando trabajamos con objetos, lo que se pasa es una copia del puntero al objeto, no del objeto, con lo que es como tener dos variables apuntando al mismo objeto:

```js
let objeto1= {
  atrib: 1
};

//ambas variables apuntan a la misma instancia
let objeto2=objeto1;

console.log(objeto2.atrib);

objeto2.atrib = 4;

console.log('¿Son iguales?',objeto2.atrib == objeto1.atrib);
//si pongo una de las dos variables a null, la otra sigue apuntando al objeto

objeto1=null;

console.log('Objeto1 es null, pero objeto2 es',JSON.stringify(objeto2));

function test(param) {
  console.log('me han pasado', param);
  param = null;
  console.log('Pongo param a' , param);
  console.log(objeto2);
}

test(objeto2);
```

Comment: Entiendo entonces, que puedo modificar el contenido que esta adentro del objeto, pero si modifico el objeto en si, se crear como otro puntero y el objeto modificado apunta ahi?

Comment: Considera que los parámetros de una función son variables locales: si creas un nuevo objeto usando una variable local, el antiguo seguirá estando apuntado por la variable fuera de la función